# SkyDrive and permanent access tokens?

Tags: access-token, onedrive

Can I access my SkyDrive using a permanent access token?

Basically, I want to grant a particular app (my own) permanent access to my personal SkyDrive account. Possible?

My use case: I'm storing some content on my personal SkyDrive, and I want to access that through my C# web app, but I don't want to have to authenticate on the client every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Asking around](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/messengerconnect/thread/5b812ea8-19f5-423e-9075-7461ee3e8bf9) on the SkyDrive API forums, it sounds like this isn't possible.

What is possible, however, is authenticate once using OAuth, then use the refresh token passed back in the initial authentication to [refresh the authentication](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/messengerconnect/thread/5b812ea8-19f5-423e-9075-7461ee3e8bf9).